# Why do Office 2007 documents open as a zip file?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, zip, iis, documents

When try to open Office 2007 documents (.pptx, .docx, .xlsx) from the intranet, my computer tries to open them as a .zip file rather than the Office document itself .

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does this only happen when using documents off the intranet?
When you open a natively stored pptx or docx file does the same thing happen?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like someone has messed with your extensions to treat them as zip files.  I'd try an Office "repair" from control panel add/remove programs to change them back.  Obviously this is not normal.